# ANTLR 2 does not generate AST file

Tags: java, gradle, antlr, antlr2

I've been given a tarball of an abandoned proprietary Java codebase that uses ANTLR 2.7.6 to generate a lexer, parser, and AST. In the tarball there is  a folder that contains amongst other things

- Name.g
- NameAST.class
- NameAST.java
- NameLexer.class
- NameLexer.java
- NameLexer.smap
- NameParser.class
- NameParser.java
- NameParser.smap

What I'm trying to do is replace the manually generated ANTLR code and ugly build scripts with a neat Gradle project. So I put the .g files in my project and included the [Gradle ANTLR plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/antlr_plugin.html).

However, when I run the Gradle build, in `build/generated-src` the NameAST.java file is not generated, leading to missing symbol errors when compiling.

I searched around, and the only thing I can find is that `buildAST` should be set, and indeed Name.g contains the following.

```
options {
    buildAST=true;
    ...
```

My grammar files are stored in `src/main/antlr/pkgname` as per the documentation, and the generated code ends up in the correct place. I cannot share the grammar files, but since I have a working JAR and the provided compiled code, I assume them to be correct.

Why is ANTLR not generating the AST files?

The `build.gradle` file thate InteliJ generated currently looks like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'antlr'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'
}

group 'Projectname'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    antlr "antlr:antlr:2.7.6"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the Gradle integration tests can help? https://github.com/gradle/gradle/search?q=buildAST&type=

Comment: I would first upgrade the grammar to ANTLRv4. It makes not much sense to keep the old grammar alive.

Comment: DOH!! It appears the *Ast.java file is not generated at all, it does not have the same `// $ANTLR : "foo.g" -> "fooLexer.java"$` comment at the top. That explains...

Comment: @MikeLischke I would... eventually. but for now there are bigger fish to fry in this codebase. Is there some sort of migration guide?

Comment: Do you have the original buildfile that invokes antlr to generate the java files? Perhaps it's simpler to invoke the [antlr ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antlr.html) in Gradle than using the antlr plugin